# Upgraded to Laravel 10 and Livewire 3. Unusual handling of values from a db table after any event is requested (but mount is fine)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I upgraded to Laravel 10 and Livewire 3.

I use a Livewire component called "details" that, on mount() retreives a number of users who will attend a seminar:

```
public $userBookings;
public $seminarid;

public function mount($sid){ 
   $this->seminarid = $sid;   
   $this->userBookings = UserSeminarAttendance::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->where("seminar_id", $this->seminarid)->get();
}
```

This works fine at this point.
In my blade page I have a livewire button that when clicked calls (at the moment) an empty function from the same details component

```
  <x-button wire:click="testfunction"  />
```

The function currently does nothing but looks like this:

```
 public function testfunction(){
     //do nothing
 }
```

As soon as I click the button I get an error on the page:

```
 Class name must be a valid object or a string
```

The log files point to the userBookings parameter as the problem:

```
    [2023-12-07 12:40:14] local.ERROR: Class name must be a valid object or a string {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class name must be a valid object or a string at C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mein-bildungspass\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\Features\\SupportLegacyModels\\EloquentCollectionSynth.php:149)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mein-bildungspass\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\Features\\SupportLegacyModels\\EloquentCollectionSynth.php(60): Livewire\\Features\\SupportLegacyModels\\EloquentCollectionSynth->loadCollection(Array)
#1 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mein-bildungspass\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents.php(216): Livewire\\Features\\SupportLegacyModels\\EloquentCollectionSynth->hydrate(Array, Array, Object(Closure))
#2 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mein-bildungspass\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents.php(199): Livewire\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents->hydrate(Array, Object(Livewire\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\ComponentContext), 'userBookings')
#3 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mein-bildungspass\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents.php(143): Livewire\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents->hydrateProperties(Object(App\\Livewire\\Bookings\\Details), Array, Object(Livewire\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\ComponentContext))
#4 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mein-bildungspass\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents.php(99): Livewire\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents->fromSnapshot(Array)
#5 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mein-bildungspass\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\LivewireManager.php(96): Livewire\\Mechanisms\\HandleComponents\\HandleComponents->update(Array, Array, Array)
#6 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mein-bildungspass\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\Mechanisms\\HandleRequests\\HandleRequests.php(85): Livewire\\LivewireManager->update(Array, Array, Array)
#7 C:.....
```

I don't understand why because the userBookings parameter has not been updated, or if it updates every time via mount() then as nothing has changed it should return with exactly the same content.
In Livewire 2 this worked perfectly fine. Something must have changed in the hydrate or eloquent system and it's wreck my page.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?